# How to query results in mySQL 3 tables deep?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables with a relationship. `posts`, `post_comments` and `post_comment_likes`

I've trying to get a list of all the `post_comment_likes` based off a single **post_id** from the `posts` table.

All my attempts and joining and nesting wheres have not worked. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Show us what you have tried? Your query and table structure.

Comment: Include db schema, sample data and desire output. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: What you have already do for this? Make a [sqlFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) is best.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. Each sub-table, has the previous one's id as a foreign constraint. For example, ```post_comments``` has a **post_id** field and ```post_comment_likes``` has a **post_comment_id** field

Answer (score 0):

If I understood coorectly you have:

TABLE POSTS
  post_id
  post_data...
  TABLE POST_COMMENTS
    post_comment_id
    post_id
    post_comment_data ...
    TABLE POST_COMMENT_LIKES
      post_comment_like_id
      post_comment_id
      post_comment_like_data...

If you want to get all the likes on all comments of a post the query should look like this:

```
SELECT * from posts p1 JOIN post_comments p2 ON(p1.post_id = p2.post_id)
JOIN post_comment_likes p3 ON (p2.post_comment_id = p3.post_comment_id)
```